# Найти значения, которые повторяются более 5 раз

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

В БД несколько сотен тысяч идентификаторов, многие из них повторяются. Какой запрос нужно направить, чтобы выгрузить те, которые повторяются 5 (и более)?

Comment: Группируете по идентификатору (GROUP BY), считаете количество (COUNT), выводите только те, кого более 5 (HAVING).

Answer (score 6):

Почитайте про агрегатные функции.

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having count(id) >= 5
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, цитирую - _Почитайте про аналитические функции_. Но в вашем запросе вы обошлись без них. Зачем о них читать?

Comment: Согласно документации oracle функция count входит в перечень аналитических функций. Так что я без них не обошёлся)

Comment: Если вы ссылаетесь на документацию, приведите ссылку (ссылка в ответе так же отсутствует).  Есть агрегатная ф-я  count и её аналитический аналог. В ответе вы использовали агрегатную.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm
Вы путаете понятия, функция одна, но имеющая два применения.

Comment: Ну раз вы так считаете, не смею настаивать.

Comment: Я прочитал ещё раз документация и вынужден согласиться. Я дал не корректный совет, поправил.

Answer (score 3):

Часто надо вместе со значением дубликата вывести соответствующие уникальные ключи для записи. В этом случае надо использовать, вместо агрегатной конструкции:

```
group by ... having count(*) ...`
```

, аналитическую (или оконную) функцию (*analytic or window function*) `COUNT`:

```sql
select id, ident from (
    select id, ident, count(*) over (partition by ident) as dups
    from idents
)
where dups >= 5
```

Подробней в документации k: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), [SQL-Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Рабочие примеры на *db<>fiddle*: [MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbe826151666af26a9e780f854f794c8) и [SQL Server 2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbe826151666af26a9e780f854f794c8)